# Who is 'you' in "I See Fire" from "The Desolation of Smaug"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, music, desolation-of-smaug

In the song "I See Fire" from *The Desolation of Smaug*, who is the 'you' referring to? Specifically, in 'I hope that you remember me'.

> Now I see fire, inside the mountain
>   I see fire, burning the trees
>   And I see fire, hollowing souls
>   And I see fire, blood in the breeze
>   And I hope that you'll remember me

Comment: The person listening?

Answer (score 8):

The opening line indicates who the song is addressed to; **The Arkenstone**.

> ***Oh, misty eye of the mountain below***
>   Keep careful watch of my brothers' souls
>   And should the sky be filled with fire and smoke
>   Keep watching over Durin's son.

Written from Thorin's perspective, he repeatedly entreats it (as if it were a person) not to forget about him and his brothers.

Answer (score 2):

The song is a classic dying lament, in which the speaker, fearing their own immanent demise, cries out to be remembered.  The genre is common across many cultures; a famous example from the American West is "[Streets of Laredo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L14UKBjC5Is)," which narrates a dying cowboy's last entreaties to a passer-by.

In the song discussed here, there is more death and destruction than of the individual speaker.  So the cry is for whoever in the future happens to hear the song to spare a memory for those who died and all that was lost.

Answer (score 1):

This song played during the credits of The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug.

In an interview, Ed Shereen said:

> "Peter said, 'Focus on the last 10 minutes. That's what the song needs
>   to reflect,'" Sheeran recalled. "He said, 'Write a song that takes the
>   audience by the hand and leads them from Middle Earth back into
>   reality.' So, yeah, I tried to do that."

The last 10 minutes of The Desolation of Smaug ends with Thorin and Co. unleashing Smaug upon Laketown. My guess would be that 'you' would refer to the dwarves, hoping for them to remember the soon to be deceased people of Laketown.